# Is there a way to schedule a function in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is it possible to make a react native app that executes a function everyday at, for example, 6:00 am. In other words an alarm that triggers a function at a specific time

Answer (score 0):

You can define scheduled background tasks using **react-native-background-task**

```
import BackgroundTask from 'react-native-background-task'
```

*Defining the task:*

```
BackgroundTask.define(() => {
  console.log('Hello World');
  BackgroundTask.finish();
});
```

*Scheduling the task*

```
BackgroundTask.schedule({
    period: 1800 // this code will run every 30 minutes.
});
```

More info can be found at https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task